# Recalling a theorem from vague memory: A monoid, in some sense, cannot "describe" the language (over one letter?) of words of prime length.

Tags: prime-numbers, soft-question, formal-languages, automata, monoid

It has been over a decade (already!) since I studied a module on formal languages & automata during my undergraduate Mathematics degree. In considering a few things in combinatorial group theory (that I cannot share just yet; I might do some day soon), I thought of a theorem I recall vaguely from back then.

**I would like some help in tracking down that theorem, please.**

It goes something like this:

> Let $A=\{a\}$. Then the language $$L=\{\varepsilon\}\cup\{ a^p\in A^*\mid p\text{ is prime}\}$$ cannot be described by a monoid "in a particular way".

Now, what that way *is* exactly, I've forgotten.

---

*(I'm not sure whether we could have $|A|>1$ with $$L'=\{w\in A^*\mid |w|\text{ is prime}\},$$ which would make sense.)*

---

I think it has something to do with regular languages. I found quite quickly online that $L$ is not regular. That rings a bell. The proof of that relies on the Pumping Lemma.

If I remember correctly, there are monoids that correspond nicely with a certain type of language, in that, for any language $K$ of that type, there is some process, let's call it $\mathcal{M}$, that produces such a monoid $\mathcal{M}(K)$ from $K$, and a process $\mathcal{L}$ that, given a monoid $M$ of the particular type, it produces a language $\mathcal{L}(M)$ from $M$ with the desired properties, such that

$$\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{M}(K))=K\quad\text{and}\quad \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{L}(M))=M.$$

But I could be wrong.

This seems relevant because I think $\mathcal {M}(L)$ is involved in the theorem in question.

---

I understand that this is not a lot to work with. There might be multiple theorems that fit the bill even. Therefore, I have included the tag [soft-question](/questions/tagged/soft-question) for good measure.

Comment: It might be because there are gaps between consecutive primes of arbitrarily large size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you refer to the [syntactic monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_monoid) of a language. See also the [French entry of Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono%C3%AFde_syntaxique), which gives more details. A key property is that a language is regular if and only if its syntactic monoid is finite. You can also check Chapter 4 of this [link](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejep/PDF/MPRI/MPRI.pdf) for reference.